# MySQL Error while using count with other queries

Tags: mysql, count, combinations

I use jdbc to run this query and successfully get results in MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT xx.x, xx.z) as `n_x|z`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT xx.w, xx.y, xx.z) as `n_w|y|z` /*,...same COUNTS*/
       FROM (SELECT x0.field0 as `x`, x0.field1 as `y`, x0.field2 as `z`, 
       x0.field3 as `w` FROM `Kind` x0 ) as xx
```

The following query also successfully generates results:

```
SELECT (1  * -1.5) as weight,
       xx.x, xx.y, xx.z, xx.w
/*The same table:*/
       FROM (SELECT x0.field0 as `x`, x0.field1 as `y`, x0.field2 as `z`, 
       x0.field3 as `w` FROM `Kind` x0 ) as xx
```

But the combination:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT xx.x, xx.z) as `n_x|z`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT xx.w, xx.y, xx.z) as `n_w|y|z` /*,... same COUNTs*/
       ,(1  * -1.5) as weight,
       xx.x, xx.y, xx.z, xx.w
/*The same table:*/
       FROM (SELECT x0.field0 as `x`, x0.field1 as `y`, x0.field2 as `z`, 
       x0.field3 as `w` FROM `Kind` x0 ) as xx
```

makes error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' xx.x, xx.y, xx.z, xx.w FROM (SELECT x0.field0 as `x`, x0.field1
>   as `y`, x0.fie' at line 1

Even removing `,(1  * -1.5) as weight` doesn't help!
I can run two queries separately but I prefer to combine them in order to have the table from the complex time-consuming query:

```
FROM (SELECT x0.field0 as `x`, x0.field1 as `y`, x0.field2 as `z`, x0.field3 as `w` FROM `Kind` x0 ) as xx"
```

be generated once.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @scaisedge I think you may have inadvertently fixed the syntax problem in your edit.

Comment: @P.Salmon  .. i have only used the curly brakes and the double quote  .for better reading  .. so you could access to  the original query are in edit mode.  anyway better reading reverted

Comment: Please show small example outputs for query 1 and query 2 and how you want the output to look for the combined query.

Comment: I'm following nothing by "combining", but just performance issues: I want a pre-generated (the result of "FROM (SELECT...") table be generated only ONCE. My first query gives two numbers, and the second generates a table and a constant weight from the pre-generated table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful  you have in the first query an aggregation on the total of the row

in the second you have rows without any aggregation

you are select different number of of rows from the two query
so you should or group by for the non aggregated  function eg:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT xx.x, xx.z) as `n_x|z`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT xx.w, xx.y, xx.z) as `n_w|y|z`
       ,(1  * -1.5) as weight,
       xx.x, xx.y, xx.z, xx.w

       FROM (SELECT x0.field0 as `x`, x0.field1 as `y`, x0.field2 as `z`, 
       x0.field3 as `w` FROM `Kind` x0 ) as xx 
       group by  weight, xx.x, xx.y, xx.z, xx.w
```

or (depending by your application needs)  use an aggregation function (eg: min()) on the not flat rows

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT xx.x, xx.z) as `n_x|z`, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT xx.w, xx.y, xx.z) as `n_w|y|z`,
       min((1  * -1.5)) as weight,
       min(xx.x), 
       min(xx.y), 
       min(xx.z), 
       min(xx.w)

       FROM (SELECT x0.field0 as `x`, x0.field1 as `y`, x0.field2 as `z`, 
       x0.field3 as `w` FROM `Kind` x0 ) as xx 
       group by  weight, xx.x, xx.y, xx.z, xx.w
```

Or as in your last comment if you want repeated  count for all the rows form xx you could use a CROSS JOIN

```
  SELECT c_xx.`n_x|z`, c_xx.`n_w|y|z`, 
         (1  * -1.5) as weight,
         xx1.x, xx1.y, xx1.z, xx1.w
  FROM (SELECT x0.field0 as `x`, x0.field1 as `y`, x0.field2 as `z`, 
         x0.field3 as `w` FROM `Kind` x0 ) xx1 

  CROSS JOIN (

      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT xx.x, xx.z) as `n_x|z`, 
             COUNT(DISTINCT xx.w, xx.y, xx.z) as `n_w|y|z` //,... same COUNTS
             FROM (SELECT x0.field0 as `x`, x0.field1 as `y`, x0.field2 as `z`, 
             x0.field3 as `w` FROM `Kind` x0 ) xx
  ) c_xx
```

Comment: I actually need to do what you mentioned. I want the final result be 2 counting numbers as a result of aggregation, and besides, a table of n rows with x,y,z,w as columns. "GROUP BY" gives me the result, but by copying same result numbers in the table n times, which wastes space.

Comment: answer updated  with a suggestion based on your comment

Comment: Anyway .. i have update my answer  (CROSS JOIN qeuery)  ..missing table alias added

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, I wanted to edit my question, not your answer! And thanks, your code works, but I don't know the difference of CROSS JOIN and GROUP BY queries because I see the same output via jdbc. Simply please answer: 1) may I be sure the mediate table (xx & xx1) is generated ONCE? 2) sure that the counting numbers don't occupy much large space being copied n times besides the table?

Comment: The Cross JOIN create a Cartesian Product between the tables involved .. so if you have a table with 2 rows and a table with 3 you obtain a table 2ith 6 rows  with all the combination of the both rows.  The group by group the columns with aggregatio function (min(), max(), count()...) depending of the different value assumed  by the columns declared in group by clause .. anyway you should take a deep immersion in SQL basic coding tutorial for a full explanation ... hope my comment is useful

Comment: So Cartesian Product is much worse than running separate queries! I never want even a large table containing the counting numbers. Attention: I JUST want 1)two numbers, and 2)a table. and the reason I don't want to run separate queries is to prevent generating twice (xx and xx1 in your code) and also space issues.

Comment: if you want the mixni "I JUST want 1)two numbers, and 2)a table" SQL give you JUST or CArtesian Product ... OR Group BY ... otherwise don't use SQL and work for presentation server or client side

Comment: OK, thanks. It is working already on client side and now I'm sure that's the best idea already